# HtmlInputRadioButton to have static ID's-ClientIDmode=static not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
      HtmlInputRadioButton radioInput = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
        radioInput.Attributes["title"] = x + "," + j;
        radioInput.ID = "radioBtn" + direction + boundIndex;
        radioInput.Value = i.ToString();
        radioInput.Name = "radio" + (isMultiSearch ? direction + i + "," + x : direction + i);
        radioInput.Checked = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(strChecked);
        radioInput.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

        phRadioBtn.Controls.Add(radioInput);
```

Hi, even though I have specified ClientIDMode="Static", the radiobutton comes up like this :

```
 <div style="display:block;">
 <input value="0" name="ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ucFlightOuterBox0$ctl04$radioLeave0" type="radio" id="radioBtnLeave5" title="0,4">
</div>
```

The code is in a webUserControl and we also have a Master Page."phRadioBtn" is a placeholder in ascx page.

Comment: I thinnk you are confusing `name` and `id`. The ID of the input is `id="radioBtnLeave5"`, as you specified. You have no control over the `name` attribute.

Comment: @VDWWD i have specified the properties in server tags now and it is coming correctly.However I have a different issue now.I have 2 radiobuttons like this : <input type="radio" id="radioBtnReturn8" value="5" name="radioReturn5" checked="True" title="0,0">
<input type="radio" id="radioBtnReturn9" value="5" name="radioReturn5" checked="False" title="0,1"> But even though first one has checked true , the second one is displayed checked.